# Register a listener with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, listener

In a new rails app, the `config/environments/production.rb` file contains this config option:

```
# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

In this case, what is a "registered listener" and how would I create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't provide a broad answer but you got me interested in this topic as well, so here are some examples from Rails Guides.

I'm quoting here chapters [10 & 11](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#rails) of [Active Support Instrumentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#rails)

> Use ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe with a block to listen to any notification.

To give a short example

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "deprecation.rails" do |name, started, finished, unique_id, data|
  # your own custom stuff
  Rails.logger.info "#{name} Received!"
end
```

Further reading:

1. Notifications: http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3
2. Deprecations: https://web.archive.org/web/20140420141413/http://8raystech.com/2011/02/07/how-to-deprecate-methods-and-constants-in-rails-3

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure why the comment in the rails code mentions `listeners` when they're called `notifications` everywhere in the documentation -- that explains why google wasn't helping.  Also, I found this article which explains how to send them to sentry (which could be modified for airbrake, etc.): http://beforeitwasround.com/2014/02/sending-rails-deprecation-warnings-to-sentry.html